# List views and Grid views with the ItemCommand and RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay, so I am learning grid views and list views... Currently what I have is a working grid view.
The following code is as follows:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName.CompareTo("Delete") == 0)
{
    int newIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    string studentEmail = GridView1.Rows[newIndex].Cells[1].Text;
    AccessDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [CourseID] = '" + studentEmail + "'";
    AccessDataSource1.Delete();
    AccessDataSource1.DataBind();
}
}
```

This works perfect for me. So I made a few other buttons for it and decided to move onto the list view and learn it. I cannot figure out why my delete button will not work. I currently can only make an update button. So, this is the code that I have so far

```
string StudentIDLabel = ((Label)(e.Item.FindControl("StudentIDLabel"))).Text.Trim();

string CourseIDLabel = ((Label)(e.Item.FindControl("CourseIDLabel"))).Text.Trim();
string GradeLabel = ((Label)(e.Item.FindControl("GradeLabel"))).Text.Trim();

AccessDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] = '" + StudentIDLabel + "' AND [CourseID] = '" + CourseIDLabel + "' AND [Grade] ='" + GradeLabel + "'";
AccessDataSource1.Delete();
AccessDataSource1.DataBind();
```

I thought it might by how my SQL statement was and I have changed it around a lot. But As it is now I get a parameter error. I am assuming it might be something isn't passing through correctly..

So I changed my SQL delete statement to

```
 AccessDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] = '" +      StudentIDLabel + "'" + CourseIDLabel + "'" + GradeLabel + "'";
```

This gives me the error :

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[StudentID] = 'aaalshehri@mail.usi.edu'CS 402'A''."

`StudentID` is the first column, follower by `CourseID` and then `Grade`.

I am just really struggling with this and maybe a little guidance from someone not as green as I am would be appreciated very much.

Thanks!

Comment: This query is not in a correct form: "DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] = '" +      StudentIDLabel + "'" + CourseIDLabel + "'" + GradeLabel + "'";

Comment: @jomsk1e I assumed that but I cannot figure out how to make it so...

Comment: May I know what's the error thrown if you use this: "DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] = '" + StudentIDLabel + "' AND [CourseID] = '" + CourseIDLabel + "' AND [Grade] ='" + GradeLabel + "'"; As stated in your question you got an error here, what's the error?

Comment: @jomsk1e - No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your query and debug your program, let's see what you got with StudentIDLabel, CourseIDLabel, GradeLabel. Maybe you are passing a NULL object in your query.

Comment: I am. So... maybe I need to make 3 strings and pass them through?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49988/discussion-between-jomsk1e-and-andrew-heid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe StudentIDLabel, CourseIDLabel, GradeLabel are NULL.

```
string StudentIDLabel = ((Label)(e.Item.FindControl("StudentIDLabel"))).Text.Trim();
string CourseIDLabel = ((Label)(e.Item.FindControl("CourseIDLabel"))).Text.Trim();
string GradeLabel = ((Label)(e.Item.FindControl("GradeLabel"))).Text.Trim();
```

You need to show us the whole method/event where you are doing this, so that we may see:

```
string StudentIDLabel = ((Label)(e.Item.FindControl("StudentIDLabel"))).Text.Trim();

string CourseIDLabel = ((Label)(e.Item.FindControl("CourseIDLabel"))).Text.Trim();
string GradeLabel = ((Label)(e.Item.FindControl("GradeLabel"))).Text.Trim();

AccessDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] = '" + StudentIDLabel + "' AND [CourseID] = '" + CourseIDLabel + "' AND [Grade] ='" + GradeLabel + "'";
AccessDataSource1.Delete();
AccessDataSource1.DataBind();
```

**--EDIT--**

You need to have the index of the button. So in the aspx code add this in the CommandArgument of the button to get the index:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

In code-behind we can now get the labels using this:

```
Label StudentIDLabel = ListView1.Item[e.CommandArgument].FindControl("StudentIDLabel");
Label CourseIDLabel = ListView1.Item[e.CommandArgument].FindControl("CourseIDLabel");
Label GradeLabel = ListView1.Item[e.CommandArgument].FindControl("GradeLabel");

AccessDataSource1.DeleteCommand = string.Format("DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] = '{0}' AND [CourseID] = '{1}' AND [Grade] = '{2}'", StudentIDLabel.Text, CourseIDLabel.Text, GradeLabel.Text)
AccessDataSource1.Delete();
AccessDataSource1.DataBind();
```

Comment: That is the entire method for it that I have.

Comment: I mean what is the event? where does 'e' came from?

Answer (score 0):

If Student Id is unique the you should be able to do

```
string sql= string.Format("DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] ={0}",
                                                             StudentIDLabel);
AccessDataSource1.DeleteCommand = sql;
```

note integer dont need quotes.

Comment: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: then it means `StudentIDLabel` is null, print/log the `sql` string.
`Response.Write(sql)` or add a breakpoint and read the `SQL`